# IBM Mobilefirst uploading .wlapp gives Throwable Connection Closed within 1 minute

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

i'm using liberty 8.5.5.5 and database DB2 10.5 and MobileFirst 7.1

While i'm uploading wlapp file(file size 50mb and above) in worklight console it says

> Throwable Connection Closed : Read failed. Possible end of stream encountered, while redirecting request to http://XX.XX.XX.XX:9080/wladmin/management-apint-apis/1.0/runtimes/sample/applications?async=true

kindly let me know, what can be the  maximum size of .wlapp file that i can upload to IBM Mobilefirst console

During upload an error is throwing approximately in 1 minute. Is there a way to increase the timeout in configuration.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no filesize restriction for .wlapp files.

Note that an iFix was recently publishing handling the timeout values when uploading .wlapp files via the console: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI59605

Make sure you are using an iFix level that is greater than 2016-03-23.
You can verify your iFix build number in the console's About screen.